# Black background with white font for first column in DT::DataTables

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a shiny app with a DT::DataTable element in which the first column is a row header and the second column contains data.  How can I change the color of the first column to be white text on a black background?  If found ways to change the column headers (section 4.3 [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html)), but I how do I get the same effect applied to the first column?

Here's some example code showing a very simplified version of the table without the desired effect.  I'm certain that adding something to the options list in the `renderDataTable` function will solve it, but I don't know what to add.

EDIT:  Below is a solution suggested by @Stéphane Laurent, which answers my original question.  However, it makes the change to all tables present on the app.  In my modified code, below, the global change is shown, but how do I target just one of the two tables?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

CSS <- HTML(
  "td.firstcol {color: white; background-color: black}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(CSS)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           DTOutput(outputId = 'tbl')
    ),
    column(3,
           DTOutput(outputId = 'tbl2')
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tbl<- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data.frame(
        Label = c('Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label4'),
        Data = c('Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4')
      ),
      rownames = FALSE, 
      colnames = "", 
      options = list(
        dom = 't',
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = 0, className = "firstcol")
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$tbl2 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data.frame(
        Label = c('Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label4'),
        Data = c('Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4')
      ),
      rownames = FALSE, 
      colnames = "", 
      options = list(
        dom = 't',
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = 0, className = "firstcol")
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

CSS <- HTML(
  "td.firstcol {color: white; background-color: black}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(CSS)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           DTOutput(outputId = 'tbl')
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tbl<- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data.frame(
        Label = c('Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label4'),
        Data = c('Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4')
      ),
      rownames = FALSE, 
      colnames = "", 
      options = list(
        dom = 't',
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = 0, className = "firstcol")
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Excellent!  This certainly answers the question I stated, however, if there are multiple tables on the same app, how do I target just one of those tables?  I modified my code, above with your solution and the detail that I don't want the effect to be global.  (I apologize for that oversight.)